# I want to create a variable for every scene in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

I am trying to implement the new Commands for iPadOS 15 and to do that you have to declare them in the App like the following example

```
@main
struct I_FeelApp: App {
    @State private var sceneCommands = GlobalCommands()

    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(globalCommands: sceneCommands)
        }
        .commands(content: { sceneCommands.commands })
    }
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that the object `GlobalCommands()` is created for the entire App not for every scene, so a change in one of the scenes will modify all of them like in the following example

[image: GIF demonstrating issue]

I have tried to create a new scene struct and create there the commands, but SwiftUI creates it for the App, no for the Scene

Creating it in a normal View doesn't work, because I can't add commands to the a View, only to a Scene

Answer (score 1):

I contacted apple about it and I found out an answer, my problem was that I had no idea about the property wrapper `@SceneStorage` and `@FocusedBinding`

So once I knew those where options I just created them and used them and it worked.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6ja307qu) a link to Apple's Code-Along about it.